# How fast do electron's quantum spin flip?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, quantum-chemistry, orbitals, spin

In a recent lecture it was taught that carbenes with their electrons in a triplet configuration do not undergo concerted reactions as one of the electrons must first undergo a *spin flip*; on what timescale does this occur?

Comment: It's briefly mentioned in the last paragraph of [this answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50277/16683).