# Which is more stable? CF2 (singlet) or CF2 (triplet)

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbene

Generally, we know that triplet carbene is more stable than singlet. But in my book, it is written that singlet difluorocarbene is more stable than triplet difluorocarbene.
What's the reason for it?

Comment: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difluorocarbene) provides some explanation for the same. If it helps...

Comment: you might be interested in this related question and answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50277/how-does-spin-flipping-of-triplet-carbenes-occur

Answer (score -1):

So generally singlet is less stable as triplet has half-filled orbitals which leads to stability.

However whenever a group that can give  electrons by back donation (examples being lone pair carriers like $\ce{-OH},$ $\ce{-NH2},$ etc. are attached, they stabilise the singlet by back donation of their lone pair into the vacant orbital of the singlet carbene.

This is similar to back bonding in $\ce{BF3}.$

Comment: i think you can add back bonding?

Answer (score -1):

Singlet carbene has a vacant p orbital. Whereas triplet carbene doesn't. Same with the case of singlet and triplet difluorocarbene. Due to the availability of vacant orbital back bond is established between F and C singlet, hence more stable.